# How to Revoke in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, dependencies, sql-grant

How to revoke user2's option while I revoke user1's option?
![I have give **select option and  GRANT OPTION** to user1 and user1 give **select option** to user2.

Now I want to revoke user1's option but if I revoke user1's option user2 
still have select option

Comment: I think it's better to think of a mysql 'user` as a 'class of user' rather than an individual - administrator, operator, guest, etc. rather than 'Bob', 'Kevin' and 'Clare', say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no dependency such that user2's privileges require the user who granted him those privileges to retain similar privileges. There is not even a requirement that user1 exist at all.

You will have to revoke privileges from user2 as a separate task. There is no automatic way of doing what you describe.

Comment: Thank a lot,and it is first time that I ask question on the stackoverflow .
The question Description is confusing,I'm very sorry . Thank you!